# Why installing foundry did'nt install lib folder

Tags: foundry

I ran the command curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash....but it did'nt install the lib folder...I am trying again and again but it does'nt install..please help me

Comment: uninstall, purge and reinstall latest version of foundry

Answer (score 0):

Adds the directory containing the Foundry binary to your system's PATH variable so you can run the `foundryup` command from anywhere.

> You can also try `forge init --no-commit`.

Or add the `lib` remaps in `foundry.toml` file.

Comment: I did what you said..but it still didn't add the lib folder